# Snapshot Jest Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsx

Currently un able to resolve this error, and haven't found a similar issue for it. but my test file won't create a snapshot file upon running tests. Any ideas what is wrong ? if you need more to know what the problem is or an idea of what it is I will be happy to provide more.

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import  ErrorView  from '../../src/components/ErrorView';
import Enzyme, { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("ErrorView.Test", () => {
    it('renders a snapshot', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<ErrorView/>).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})
```

Comment: You could try toMatchInlineSnapshot?

Comment: what is the error while running test script ? Is your component using withRouter or withStyles HOC ?

Comment: are you getting an error (and if so can you share it)?  can you share the code for `ErrorView`?  also, I'm a little curious why you are importing both `react-test-renderer` and `Enzyme`..

Comment: Did you get any error?